# Spacings of rows in PlotLegends

Tags: legending

I would like to gain control over the distance between the rows in PlotLegends to make more compact legends. I am using Mathematica 10.
This is my code:

```
ListPlot[{Table[x, {x, 0, 10}],Table[0.5*x, {x, 0, 10}],Table[2 - 0.5*x, {x, 0, 10}],Table[4 - 0.1*x, {x, 0, 10}]},Joined -> True,PlotStyle -> {{Red, AbsoluteThickness[4], Dashed}, {Red,AbsoluteThickness[4]},{Blue,AbsoluteThickness[4],Dashed}, {Blue, AbsoluteThickness[4]}},FrameLabel -> {"space [microns]", "strength [GPa]"},PlotRange -> {{0, 12}, {0, 6}}, PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[.05],GridLines -> {{0}, None},PlotLegends -> Placed[LineLegend[{Style["one", FontSize -> 20],Style["two", FontSize -> 20],Style["three", FontSize -> 20],Style["four", FontSize -> 20]},
LegendFunction -> (Framed[#, Background -> LightGray,FrameStyle -> Directive[Black, Thick]] &),LegendMargins -> 0], Scaled[{0.6, 0.4}]]]
```

Comment: add the option `"Spacings" -> .5` to `LineLegend`?

Comment: this is what I was missing. Thanks!

Comment: Luigi, posted the comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the option

```
"Spacings" -> .5
```

in `LineLegend` gives

[image]